# css :focus transition on form field elements

Tags: css

I have a form where I have used a css transition to become fully opaque using the `:hover` state (no JavaScript)

```
#containerDiv hover:#myForm{etc}
```

I would like the state to remain when the user places the cursor inside any form field `:focus` even when the mouse may no longer hover over the form. However I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax to make this happen.

```
#containerDiv #myForm ??? focus:MyFormElement{etc}
```

I suspect this may only be possible using JavaScript because of the cascade order. However, I don't want to use JavaScript to do this to keep things light.

Comment: Looking at css conditional rules http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-conditional/

Answer (score 1):

Give your form and focused element the same css values like this

```
#containerDiv #myForm:hover , #containerDiv #myForm:hover MyFormElement:focus {etc}
```

the pseudo-selectors go after the elements demonstrated above